# navigation_stack send goal

Tags: navigation, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i try to move my robot in gazebo via the navigation stack. but i have no idea how to send goals to him, andhttp://www.ros.org/wiki/navigation/Tutorials/SendingSimpleGoals does not work, there comes just a compiler error

```
`/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/simple_navigation_goals.dir/src/simple_navigation_goals.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
  /usr/bin/ld: note: 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
  /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status`
```

are there some other easy examples or have you one ? it can also be in python.Or you can help me solve the compiler error (:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

# Set the build type.  Options are:
#  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
#  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
#  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
#  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
#set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo)

rosbuild_init()

#set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory
set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
#set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

#uncomment if you have defined messages
#rosbuild_genmsg()
#uncomment if you have defined services
#rosbuild_gensrv()

#common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
#rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
#rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
#rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
#rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
#target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
rosbuild_add_executable(simple_navigation_goals src/simple_navigation_goals.cpp)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39610/navigation_stack-send-goal/) by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 336 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Erwan R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2176/erwan-r./) on 2012-07-24**:
Check your boost version to be sure that you have thread_data_base included.

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-24**:
i have boost 1.46.1 and i have libboos-thread1.46.1 in /var/lib/dpkg/info.... where shuld be the thread_data_base ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The error message you get says that you should try adding boost to your linker command. Try that. Just uncomment the two boost related lines in your CMakeLists.txt, i.e. add the following:

```
rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pkohout](https://answers.ros.org/users/2803/pkohout/) on 2012-07-25**:
the old error is gone but i get another, it is:
Cannot specify link libraries for target "simple_navigation_goals" which is
not built by this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
CMakeLists.txt:28 (rosbuild_link_boost)
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
any ideas ?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2012-08-08**:
@coon you should ask this as a separate question.

**Comment by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) on 2012-10-08**:
@coon you need to put the line rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread) under the line rosbuild_add_executable()